# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I'm working on building a drag and drop card game. I'm not familiar with using the library react-dnd I wonder if this has something to do with it. If I use data already on the file, it works fine, but if I have to fetch the data, it creates This error.

As I said, this usually happens when I use useEffect Somebody has a better idea of how to do this, please let me know.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import { useDrop } from 'react-dnd';
import './Table.css';

const API_Data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    url: 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/6H.png',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    url: 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/aceDiamonds.png',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    url: 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/7C.png',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    url: 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/6H.png',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    url: 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/aceDiamonds.png',
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    url: 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/7C.png',
  },
];

function Table() {
  const [playersCard, setPlayersCard] = useState([]);
  const [potA, setPotA] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      url: 'https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/6H.png',
    },
  ]);
  const [potB, setPotB] = useState([]);
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const [, dropA] = useDrop(() => ({
    accept: 'card',
    drop: (item) => handleAddToPotA(item.id),
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
    }),
  }));

  const handleAddToPotA = (id) => {
    const newCard = playersCard.filter((card) => id === card.id);
    console.log(`newCard`, newCard);

    setPotA((oldCard) => [...oldCard, newCard[0]]);
  };
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const [, dropB] = useDrop(() => ({
    accept: 'card',
    drop: (item) => handleAddToPotB(item.id),
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
    }),
  }));

  const handleAddToPotB = (id) => {
    const newCard = playersCard.filter((card) => id === card.id);
    setPotB((oldCard) => [...oldCard, newCard[0]]);
    console.log(newCard);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setPlayersCard(API_Data);
    return () => {};
  }, []);

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  if (!playersCard) {
    return <div></div>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="table-page">
      <div className="center-table">
        <div className="pot-a" ref={dropA}>
          {potA &&
            potA.map((card) => {
              return <Card url={card?.url} id={card.id} key={card.id} />;
            })}
        </div>
        <div className="pot-b" ref={dropB}>
          {potB &&
            potB.map((card) => {
              return <Card url={card.url} id={card.id} key={card.id} />;
            })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="players-card">
        {playersCard.map((card) => {
          return <Card url={card.url} id={card.id} key={card.id} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: something that I forgot to mention the error doesn't happen on playerCard.it occurs when I try to move the card from playerCard to potA or potB

Answer (score 0):

Because playersCard is not initialized yet.

try to check undefined first

```
<div className="players-card">
        {playersCard.length > 0 && playersCard.map((card) => {
          return <Card url={card.url} id={card.id} key={card.id} />;
        })}
      </div>
```

Comment: something that I forgot to mention the error doesn't happen on playerCard.it occurs when I try to move the card from playerCard to potA or potB

Answer (score 0):

The `useDrop()` hook from `react-dnd` takes two arguments: the config function, and a **dependency array** used to indicate whether the config function can be memo-ized.

- https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/use-drop#usedrop

Try changing each `useDrop()` hook in your code to include a dependency array containing every variable/function reference that you are using inside the config.

###### Example #1

Here I have added a dependency array of `[handleAddToPotA]` because you're referencing that function within the config:

```
const [, dropA] = useDrop(
  () => ({
    accept: "card",
    drop: (item) => handleAddToPotA(item.id),
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
    }),
  }),
  [handleAddToPotA]
);
```

###### Example #2

For the whole file, I have:

- Added a dependency array to both `useDrop()` hooks
- Converted `handleAddToPotA` and `handleAddToPotB` to use React's `useCallback()` hook (which each have their own dependency array of `[playersCard]`)

See below:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
import { useDrop } from "react-dnd";
import "./Table.css";

const API_Data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    url: "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/6H.png",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    url: "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/aceDiamonds.png",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    url: "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/7C.png",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    url: "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/6H.png",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    url: "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/aceDiamonds.png",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    url: "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/7C.png",
  },
];

function Table() {
  const [playersCard, setPlayersCard] = useState([]);
  const [potA, setPotA] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      url: "https://deckofcardsapi.com/static/img/6H.png",
    },
  ]);
  const [potB, setPotB] = useState([]);

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  const handleAddToPotA = useCallback(
    (id) => {
      const newCard = playersCard.filter((card) => id === card.id);
      if (newCard.length > 0) {
        setPotA((oldCards) => [...oldCards, newCard[0]]);
      }
    },
    [playersCard]
  );
  const [, dropA] = useDrop(
    () => ({
      accept: "card",
      drop: (item) => handleAddToPotA(item.id),
      collect: (monitor) => ({
        isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
      }),
    }),
    [handleAddToPotA]
  );

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  const handleAddToPotB = useCallback(
    (id) => {
      const newCard = playersCard.filter((card) => id === card.id);
      if (newCard.length > 0) {
        setPotB((oldCards) => [...oldCards, newCard[0]]);
      }
    },
    [playersCard]
  );
  const [, dropB] = useDrop(
    () => ({
      accept: "card",
      drop: (item) => handleAddToPotB(item.id),
      collect: (monitor) => ({
        isOver: !!monitor.isOver(),
      }),
    }),
    [handleAddToPotB]
  );

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  useEffect(() => {
    setPlayersCard(API_Data);
    return () => {};
  }, []);

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  if (!playersCard) {
    return <div></div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="table-page">
      <div className="center-table">
        <div className="pot-a" ref={dropA}>
          {potA &&
            potA.map((card) => {
              return <Card url={card?.url} id={card.id} key={card.id} />;
            })}
        </div>
        <div className="pot-b" ref={dropB}>
          {potB &&
            potB.map((card) => {
              return <Card url={card.url} id={card.id} key={card.id} />;
            })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="players-card">
        {playersCard.map((card) => {
          return <Card url={card.url} id={card.id} key={card.id} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

Answer (score -1):

A Possible Reason:

- Check your function and method names for typos